# Mime Type Excel Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mime-types

In laravel 4.2, what is the mime type for excel (.xls or .xlsx)?

```
$rules = array('file' => 'mimes:png,jpeg,jpg,bmp,pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,txt');
```

it doesnt work like this.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx - an official list of Office mimes. Try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel use Symfony and Symfony use unreliable class FileInfo. I guess, it returns it text/plain for xls. The solution is get the file extension and then validate it.

For example:

```
$file = Input::get('file');
$ext = strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());

$validator = Validator::make(
     array('ext' => $ext),
     array('ext' => 'in:png,jpeg,jpg,bmp,pdf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx,txt')
);
```